# Restricting WMS GetFeatureInfo properties in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

I am working on a WMS-based OpenLayers project, which is pulling in data from the BGS WMS Servers. We're pulling the 1:50k bedrock layer from this WMS:

https://map.bgs.ac.uk/arcgis/services/BGS_Detailed_Geology/MapServer/WMSServer?

In OpenLayers 3 I am trying to query the WMS and display the attributes in an iFrame beneath the OpenLayers map. Using the following code, I am able to get the full metadata to display beneath the map.

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
            var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
            var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
                evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
                {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
            if (url) {
              document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
                  '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
            }
          });
```

The thing is, this pulls in ALL of the metadata and I would like to restrict it to just one or two fields, such as LEX, LEX_RCS_D or MAX_TIME_D (see [field names here](https://map.bgs.ac.uk/arcgis/services/BGS_Detailed_Geology/MapServer/WMSServer?version=1.3.0&request=GetFeatureInfo&format=image/png&layers=BGS.50k.Bedrock&query_layers=BGS.50k.Bedrock&info_format=text/html&i=200&j=400&radius=0&crs=CRS:84&BBOX=-2.215,50.991,-2.205,50.995&WIDTH=450&HEIGHT=450&styles=default))

I'm not a user of JavaScript, so I'm having difficulties modifying the code.

After some research online, I came across the propertyName parameter, which I've tried implementing, although I'm not even sure this is what I'm looking for.

```
{'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'}, {propertyName: 'LEX'}
```

Given the way the BGS WMS is configured, is it even possible to limit the attributes which are pulled out on the GetFeatureInfo request?

Answer (score 2):

> Given the way the BGS WMS is configured, is it even possible to limit the attributes which are pulled out on the GetFeatureInfo request?

No.

The `propertyName parameter` you have come across is a vendor specific option provided by GeoServer for WMS, but this BGS service is not a GeoServer service; so you will not be able to use `propertyName` to limit the attributes retrieved from a GetFeatureInfo request.

Comment: Thanks - I had wondered if I'd misunderstood a concept somewhere. There must be another BGS layer online somewhere then, because their own web map queries at the [GeoIndex](http://mapapps2.bgs.ac.uk/geoindex/home.html) display selected fields only.

Comment: GeoIndex uses an ArcGIS REST interface internally, not a WMS

Comment: You might be able to cascade the WMS through another WMS service and limit the output that way